# Regarding explicit template instantiation and static variables in base classes: compiler bug or valid interpretation of the spec?

Tags: c++

It is my understanding (C++ Common Knowledge, Item 61; Solaris Studio C++ User's Guide) that an explicit instantiation of a template class will result in all of its members being instantiated.  However, I have found a situation where this is not the case with the Solaris Studio C++ compiler.  As this compiler often acts very differently from others while still obeying the spec (usually in a stricter sense), I am asking any C++ template experts if the behavior I am seeing is valid.

My situation is that I have a template class "Derived" that inherits from a template class "Base" specialized to "Derived".  "Base<Derived>" contains a static variable "tracer" that must be present in the object file after compilation (in my full code, this is related to registering "Derived" with a Factory).  With most compilers (GCC, Open64, Intel, Clang, Visual C++), this is the case.  However, with Solaris Studio, this only occurs if "Derived"'s constructor is NOT implemented in its definition.  Otherwise, "tracer" is not put in the object file (and "Derived" would not be registered with the Factory).

Here is some minimal code to demonstrate the problem:

#### Base.h:

```cpp
#ifndef BASE_H_
#define BASE_H_
template<typename T>
class Base {
 public:
  Base() : dummy_(g_tracer_) { }
 private:
  bool dummy_;
  static bool g_tracer_;
};

template<typename T>
bool Base<T>::g_tracer_ = true;
#endif  // BASE_H_
```

#### DerivedA.cc:

```cpp
#include "Base.h"
template<typename T>
class DerivedA : private Base<DerivedA<T> > {
 public:
  DerivedA(int val);
  T GetVar() const;
 private:
  T var_;
};

template<typename T>
DerivedA<T>::DerivedA(const int val) : var_(val) { }

template<typename T>
T DerivedA<T>::GetVar() const { return var_; }

// Explicit Instantiation
template class DerivedA<double>;
```

#### DerivedB.cc:

```cpp
#include "Base.h"
template<typename T>
class DerivedB : private Base<DerivedB<T> > {
 public:
  DerivedB(int val) : var_(val) { }
  T GetVar() const;
 private:
  T var_;
};

template<typename T>
T DerivedB<T>::GetVar() const { return var_; }

// Explicit Instantiation
template class DerivedB<double>;
```

If I compile the ".cc" files with `sunCC -c` and run `nm` on the resulting object files, "DerivedA.o" contains a symbol for "g_tracer_" (`0000000000000000 V __1cEBase4nIDerivedA4Cd___Jg_tracer__`), but "DerivedB.o" does not.  (Note: even if I use the option `-template=wholeclass`, the symbol is still not present in the output.)  Using any other compiler, both object files would contain a symbol corresponding to "g_tracer_".

Is this valid behavior, or is this an obscure compiler bug?  My knowledge of the C++ spec isn't sufficient for me to be convinced either way.  (In fact, I just saw an answer here suggesting that explicit instantiation might not instantiate base class members, so now I'm especially confused.)  I'd appreciate any clarifications on this matter.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hm, have you actually tried to set up a program which **uses** the instantiated classes? Since you are only creating a "library" (which is something the standard is not talking about at all), I believe the compiler (or better, the librarian) is allowed to do whatever it wants. Try to set up a program which links all the stuff together. I assume that without some specific linker configuration regarding instantiation of unused symbols or some trickery to enforce the usage you will end up with no instantiation of `g_tracers` at all - the linker will simply not add them to the program.

Cheers,

Paul

Comment: In my full code, "tracer" is set to the result of a function whose side effect is to register the class with the factory during static initialization.  When linking, we use `-Wl,--undefined=` (or a linker script with `EXTERN()`) to ensure that "tracer" is linked, but in order to know the symbol name (which is not portable), we essentially grep for "tracer" in the output of `nm`.
In principle, `-Wl,--whole-archive` should accomplish the same thing (with more bloat), but this still doesn't work if the "tracer" symbol isn't in the object file.
I can link to a larger example if that would help.

Comment: To clarify, if I explicitly use "Derived" in a program, "tracer" is indeed added to the output (as the compiler got to see all the headers again).  But if I don't (and only mention its parent), then no amount of linker trickery can resurrect it from Sun's "DerivedB.o".  Is it the case, then, that our use of `-Wl,--undefined=`/`EXTERN` is not a portable way to accomplish factory registration in the context of the relevant standards?  ("Portable" in the ideal sence, rather than pragmatic/emperical.)

Comment: From what I can tell, there is no portability guarantee for such concepts. I have used similar design for registering types ("tracers") when I was dealing with a system consisting of pluggable modules. You need to ensure that the dynamic initializers for g_tracers will be run. The only way to do that is to make the linkers see their usage - I'll edit my answer not enough space in the comment box...